# Need Help Making Java Script Discord Music Bot

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, bots, discord

I have tried to use this code to make a discord music bot but i am getting error telling me i need ffmpeg, but how would I implement it into this code?

index.js file

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

var youtube = require('./youtube.js');


var ytAudioQueue = [];
var dispatcher = null;

bot.on('message', function(message) {
    var messageParts = message.content.split(' ');
    var command = messageParts[0].toLowerCase();
    var parameters = messageParts.splice(1, messageParts.length);

    switch (command) {

        case "-join" : 
        message.reply("Attempting to join channel " + parameters[0]);
        JoinCommand(parameters[0], message);
        break;
    
        case "-play" :
        PlayCommand(parameters.join(" "), message);
        break;

        case "-playqueue":
        PlayQueueCommand(message);
        break;
    }
});


    function PlayCommand(searchTerm) {
        if(bot.voiceConnections.array().length == 0) {
            var defaultVoiceChannel = bot.channels.find(val => val.type === 'voice').name;
            JoinCommand(defaultVoiceChannel);
        }
        youtube.search(searchTerm, QueueYtAudioStream);
    }

    function PlayQueueCommand(message) {
        var queueString = "";

        for(var x = 0; x < ytAudioQueue.length; x++) {
            queueString += ytAudioQueue[x].videoName + ", ";
        }
        queueString = queueString.substring(0, queueString.length - 2);
        message.reply(queueString);
    }

    function JoinCommand(ChannelName) {
        var voiceChannel = GetChannelByName(ChannelName);

        if (voiceChannel) {
            voiceChannel.join();
            console.log("Joined " + voiceChannel.name);
        }
        
        return voiceChannel;
        
    }

    /* Helper Methods */

    function GetChannelByName(name) {
        var channel = bot.channels.find(val => val.name === name);
        return channel;
    }

  

    function QueueYtAudioStream(videoId, videoName) {
        var streamUrl = youtube.watchVideoUrl + videoId;

        if (!ytAudioQueue.length) {
            ytAudioQueue.push(
                {
                    'streamUrl' : streamUrl,
                    'videoName' : videoName
                }
            );
            console.log('Queued audio ' + videoName);
            PlayStream(ytAudioQueue[0].streamUrl);
        }
        else {
            ytAudioQueue.push(
                {
                    'streamUrl' : streamUrl,
                    'videoName' : videoName
                }
            );
        }
        console.log("Queued audio " + videoName);
    }

    function PlayStream(streamUrl) {
        const streamOptions = {seek: 0, volume: 1};

        if (streamUrl) {
            const stream = ytdl(streamUrl, {filter: 'audioonly'});

            if (dispatcher == null) {
                var voiceConnection = bot.voiceConnections.first();

                if(voiceConnection) {
                    console.log("Now Playing " + ytAudioQueue[0].videoname);
                    dispatcher = bot.voiceConnections.first().playStream(stream, streamOptions);

                    dispatcher.on('end', () => {
                        dispatcher = null;
                        PlayNextStreamInQueue();
                    });

                    dispatcher.on('error', (err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                dispatcher = bot.voiceConnections.first().playStream(stream, streamOptions);
            }
            
        }
    }

    function PlayNextStreamInQueue() {
        ytAudioQueue.splice(0, 1);

        if (ytAudioQueue.length != 0) {
            console.log("now Playing " + ytAudioQueue[0].videoName);
            PlayStream(ytAudioQueue[0].streamUrl);
        }
    }


bot.login(config.token);
```

youtube.js file

```js
var request = require('superagent');

const API_KEY = "My API KEY";
const WATCH_VIDEO_URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";

exports.watchVideoUrl = WATCH_VIDEO_URL;

exports.search = function search(searchKeywords, callback) {
  var requestUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search' + '?part=snippet&q=' + escape(searchKeywords) + '&key=' + API_KEY;

  request(requestUrl, (error, response) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

      var body = response.body;
      if (body.items.length == 0) {
        console.log("I Could Not Find Anything!");
        return;
      }
      for (var item of body.items) {
        if (item.id.kind == 'youtube#video') {
          callback(item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
          return;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Unexpected error!");
      return;
    }
  });

  return;

};
```

Error I am getting when I try to run code :

Joined General

C:\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\pcm\FfmpegConverterEngine.

js:80

throw new Error(

^

Error: FFMPEG was not found on your system, so audio cannot be played. Please make
 sure FFMPEG is installed and in your PATH.

Comment: The errors pretty clear. Install FFMPEG (I'm guessing it's a codec), and put the directory on your PATH.

Comment: I have added it to my path however I am still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to download/extract FFMPEG and make it as your PATH/System variable[environment variable]

Make sure that you have it as your System variable like this :
[image: Screenshot]

The System Variable should named as 'FFMPEG' and should be directed to where the execution(`.exe`) file is. It should be in a folder called 'bin' in your FFMPEG folder.

You can google/search online on how to add a new System/PATH variable for your specific OS.

Comment: I have done this and added ffmpeg to my path however I am still getting the error. :/

Comment: @Gambino please state whatever solution you have tried that does not work.

Comment: I went to System, Advanced system settings, Environment Variables, System variables, and added FFMPEG and set the value to where the .exe file was. then I restarted the bot and tried to play a song then the error came up again. So I did what I tried before this and went into the System variables,  selected the Variable named Path and hit Edit, then New in the Edit environment variables window and direct it to the folder containing ffmpeg.exe. and it still gave me the error I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I basically followed instructions from here (http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows)